# Where can i find microsoft.office.infopath.dll in Windows 7

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-office

I installed Microsoft office professional 2003 package, which also includes Microsoft office infopath, but `microsoft.office.infopath.dll` is missing in .Net Framework Components and in GAC.
Please give a appropriate solution

Comment: no programming content: try superuser.com

Comment: @kalai: Will you accept my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

On my Machine (default install directory) it is found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12